# How to install Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 on Ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: software-installation

I am using Ubuntu 19.04. How do I install Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 on it?

Comment: Welcome to AU.  Please review [How to ask a good question](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.  For instance, did you try answers already given for other versions of Ubuntu? Where did you have a problem?

Answer (score 2):

[Visual Studio is an IDE for Windows](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/), so you can't install it on Ubuntu. You can try to install it with Wine, however, I wouldn't attach too much hope for that.

And there is a free [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/?wt.mc_id=vscom_downloads) which is an extendable text editor and it has a Linux edition. You can install it as a snap:

`sudo snap install --classic code`

Or, alternatively [you can download a .deb package from the Microsoft's website](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=760868). And install it like:

`sudo apt install ./<file>.deb`

Comment: how can i use wine for installing Visual Studio?

Comment: Download the .exe installer for Windows, then install it with  `wine <vs-2017-executable-name>.exe`, but it is qualified as "garbage" on the WineHQ database: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=35535

Which means, it isn't usable.

One more alternative is Monodevelop, if you are developing in C#, which is a cross-platform IDE, but not not as feature rich as Visual Studio: https://www.monodevelop.com/

Comment: after download .exe and download wine then sudo ./visual studio ? it is right